# Cannot install MySQL 5.5 with django 1.8.2 on Windows 7 64bit

Tags: python, mysql, django, windows-7-x64

I had MySQL 5.5 installed as part of XAMPP stack on Win7 64bit. I am using python 3.4 and I want to try out Django. So I installed Django using pip from command line and it worked fine with the default sqlite3 db.

To integrate MySQL, I see installed 'mysql-connector-python' using pip. I changed the engine to ''mysql.connector.django'. I changed the settings.py file with the DATABASE settings as follows:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': { 
        'ENGINE': 'mysql.connector.django', 
        'NAME': 'db',                     
        'USER': 'root',
        'PASSWORD': '',
    }
}
```

When I check the server, I get the following error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 111, in load_backend
    return import_module('%s.base' % backend_name)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\mysql\connector\django\base.py", line 50, in <module>
    from django.db.backends import (BaseDatabaseFeatures, BaseDatabaseOperations,
ImportError: cannot import name 'BaseDatabaseFeatures'

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 10, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 338, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\core\management\__init__.py", line 312, in execute
    django.setup()
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\__init__.py", line 18, in setup
    apps.populate(settings.INSTALLED_APPS)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\registry.py", line 108, in populate
    app_config.import_models(all_models)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\apps\config.py", line 198, in import_models
    self.models_module = import_module(models_module_name)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\importlib\__init__.py", line 109, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2254, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2237, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 2226, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1200, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1129, in _exec
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 1471, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 321, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\contrib\auth\models.py", line 41, in <module>
    class Permission(models.Model):
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 139, in __new__
    new_class.add_to_class('_meta', Options(meta, **kwargs))
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\base.py", line 324, in add_to_class
    value.contribute_to_class(cls, name)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\models\options.py", line 250, in contribute_to_class
    self.db_table = truncate_name(self.db_table, connection.ops.max_name_length())
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\__init__.py", line 36, in __getattr__
    return getattr(connections[DEFAULT_DB_ALIAS], item)
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 240, in __getitem__
    backend = load_backend(db['ENGINE'])
  File "c:\Python34\lib\site-packages\django\db\utils.py", line 129, in load_backend
    raise ImproperlyConfigured(error_msg)
django.core.exceptions.ImproperlyConfigured: 'mysql.connector.django' isn't an available database backend.
Try using 'django.db.backends.XXX', where XXX is one of:
    'base', 'mysql', 'oracle', 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'sqlite3'
Error was: cannot import name 'BaseDatabaseFeatures'
```

Found a bug filed here-
https://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76752

For resolution, it suggests-

```
Adjust the backend to the changes in Django API. See the release notes for details:
https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/releases/1.8/#database-backend-api
```

How do I adjust the backend? I have no idea how to proceed.

Comment: @karthikr no, mysql-connector is not compatible with mysqldb and supplies its own Django db backend.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Installing from the forked version works.

```
pip install git+https://github.com/multiplay/mysql-connector-python
```

From [Github repo](https://github.com/multiplay/mysql-connector-python) description this one is

> Fork of version 2.0.4 of mysql-connector-python (and probably rebased
>   at points) until upstream issues are fixed

Got the reference from [bug url](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=76752).

Comment: I am facing the same error with python 3.4 django 1.8 windows 8 mysql database. I have tried a lot of things. Also installed mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz. Please help

Answer (score 1):

The latest version of mysql-connector-python works with Django 1.8. You can get it from the mysql website.
(version mysql-connector-python-2.1.3)

Install it from the MySQL:

```
pip install http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-Python/mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz
```

Comment: I am facing the same error with python 3.4 django 1.8 windows 8 mysql database. I have tried a lot of things. Also installed mysql-connector-python-2.1.3.tar.gz. Please help